# Reclassifying raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, classification, reclassify

I'm modelling species distributions using Maxent. Maxent produced probability of occurrence/habitat suitability maps for my study species. These raster maps have values ranging from 0 to 1.

I want to transform these maps in a binary map of suitable and unsuitable areas, by using a threshold.

It would be something like this:

From 0 to threshold (not included) = 0 ;
From threshold (included) to 1 = 1

I thought about using the QGIS tool r.reclass, but I'm failing to understand how to provide the (included) or (not included) information to the reclassify rules.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Use [raster calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator) with `raster@1 >= N`, where `raster@1` is the name of your raster layer and band, and `N` is the threshold value.